# Search multiple Mongo columns for multiple entries

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, mongodb

I have made a nice pageing system that is ajax dynamic with .net, mongodb, and twitter bootstrap. Everything works great but now I would like to have a text box where the user can search and ajax/mongo driver search all fields of a collection and return the results, a perfect example of my goal can be seen [here](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) at the datatables plugin. I have tried a few things such as combing all of the columns with an or:

```
Query.Or(
    Query.Matches("Name", new BsonRegularExpression(query, "i")),
    Query..Matches("Facility.Name", new BsonRegularExpression(query, "i")),
    etc...
)
```

Which I suppose in theory is the way you could do it, however I was hopeing for a solution a little more universal. When you use the data tables plugin i linked it will search all data no matter what and organize it properly (i realize this is html not a DB) but is there a systematic way to do this with MongoDB? Any one have any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB [text indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) will allow you to [create a text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/) on specific fields within a document or on all fields within each document. After you've created the index you can use the [$text](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) operator to performa a search.